# Angular - Llamando api laravel con token Bearer no funciona (me devuelve 'No autorizado')

Tags: angular, api, servicio, tokens

tengo una api en la que llamando a **api-url/user** me da el usuario logeado (pasandole un token, de tipo **Bearer**). 
 La api necesita un Header de este tipo:

```
Bearer ${token}
```

Mi servicio que llama a la url que obtiene el usuario logeado es esta :

```
  public home(){
    let token = this.authService.getToken();
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    console.log('-- HEADERS --');
    console.log(headers);

    return this.http.get(this.REST_API_SERVER+this.HOME,{headers:headers});
  }
```

Lo que pasa que me dice que no tenog autorizacion, comprobe el header con el log, y me sale vacio:

```
HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
headers: Map(0)
[[Entries]]
No properties
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
```

No se porque sale vacio, no se si es por eso que no funciona el `HttpHeaders`. Lo he probado en **postman** y si funciona, pero aqui no, y las cabeceras son las mismas (en postman tiene algo mas pero propias de postman, que no afecta a mi backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos de la clase `HttpHeaders` son inmutables por eso el método `append()` no agrega las cabeceras al objeto actual sino que retorna un clon del objeto original con las nuevas cabeceras agregadas.

Puedes crear el objeto `headers` así:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders({
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer token"
  });
```

O guardando la referencia al nuevo objeto retornado por `append()`:

```
 let headers = new HttpHeaders();
 headers = headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
 headers = headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer token");
```

[Referencia](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-and-updating-headers)